# Win32API replicate Spy++ window-information capabilities within Python

Tags: winapi, user32

I have a third-party GUI program that I'm wrapping with a Python class (using ctypes).

Are there Win32 API functions that can do the following?

1) Obtain the window handle for a window at a given screen location.

2) Obtain the window handle for a Button or Static window with a given caption.

3) Send text to an Edit window.

4) Extract text from a RICHEDIT instance.

I have WinSpy (a Spy++-type app) and know that it's possible to obtain window handles and captions using that tool, but I need something that works within Python.

I assume that Python's ctypes gives me access to any function within the Win32 API, so I've been scanning MSDN (especially [this windows/messages section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632586(v=VS.85).aspx)). I can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was more of a Windows API question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558.aspx)
2. [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx) to find a child of a window with a given class and name (caption). Repeat operation to get through each parent-child indirection. [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494.aspx) can be helpful too.
3. [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952.aspx) + [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644.aspx)
4. [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952.aspx) + [`WM_GETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627.aspx) or [`EM_STREAMOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774304.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding a very simple example for WM_GETTEXT with pywin32 and figured here might be a good place to add one, since it answers part of the question:

```
MAX_LENGTH = 1024

handle = # A handle returned from FindWindowEx, for example

buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(MAX_LENGTH)
length = win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, MAX_LENGTH, buffer)

result = buffer[:length]
```